# Difference between Null-space(A) and Null space$(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two linearly independent vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $R^3$; span a plane $P^1$. Then any vector normal to the plane $P^1$ will be in the $N(A)$ or in the $N(A^T)$ ? (Here, $N(.) = Nullspace$.)

On the same line; If I take a matrix $A$ made up of $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $R^3$; as columns of $A$. Then $A = QR $; The full QR factorisation will result in a 3rd vector $v_3$; which will be in the normal direction. Which sub-space will this vector be in? $N(A)$ or $N(A^T)$ ?

As an extension to this question; If we have 2 sets of linearly independent vectors in $R^3$ ; $ (x_1 , y_1) $ and $ (x_2 , y_2) $ such that they span planes $P^1$ and $P^2$ respectively; then the vector q1 coming from a full QR factorisation of a matrix A with $ (x_1 , y_1) $ as columns; i.e Q will have the vector $q_1$ which will be orthogonal to both $x_1$ and $y_1$ and similarly the vector $q_2$ coming from QR factorisation of matrix B with $ (x_2 , y_2) $ ;

Further is we take another QR factorisation with  $ (q_1 , q_2) $ as columns; then we will find a vector $q_3$ which will be orthogonal to both $ q_1$ and $q_2$ ; But is this enough to prove that the vector lie on the intersections of planes $ P^1$ and $ P^2$ ? Can't the vector $q_3$ lie parallel to both planes and not on any one of them or not on both of them!

Comment: Hint: $A$ is $3 \times 2$ and hence $N(A)$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: How do you get this third vector? $Q$ is $3\times2$ and $R$ is $2\times2$

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos I am doing full QR.

Comment: What does it mean for a vector to "come from a QR factorization"?

Comment: @user7530 I have updated the question accordingly. Actually I meant; the full QR factorisations 'Q' will have the vector 1 which will be orthogonal to both 1 and 1

Comment: I hope the question is clear; if not kindly tell me! I'll update and make it better. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of matrix multiplication by a vector, $Av$, as taking a linear combination of the columns (with the weights of the combination in the vector). So if $A$'s columns are linearly-independent vectors, $A$ has no null space.

You can also think of matrix multiplication as dot products of rows of $A$ with $v$. A vector $v$ perpendicular to the columns of $A$ is therefore in the nullspace of $A^T$, since $A^Tv = 0$ (the entries of $A^Tv$ are dot products of the columns of $A$ with $v$).